# Odoo redirect with JSON

Tags: odoo

I need to redirect user by pressing a button.
The button code is like that:

```py
from odoo.http import request
...
@api.one
def go_away(self):
    return request.redirect('http://example.com/api.jsp?user=1&id=12')
```

Odoo raises an error:

```py
AttributeError: 'JsonRequest' object has no attribute 'redirect'
```

When i try this:

```py
werkzeug.utils.redirect(url)
```

Odoo says:

```py
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'routing_type'
```

I can understand what is wrong and how can i redirect user with JSON data in a link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that i can redirect like this:

```py
    @api.multi
    def go_away(self)
    return {
        'type': 'ir.actions.act_url',
        'url': url,
        'target': 'self',
    }
```